# Running the Postgres CLI client from a Kubernetes jumpbox

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have setup a Postgres pod on my Kubernetes cluster, and I am trying to troubleshoot it a bit.

I would like to use the [official Postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) and deploy it to my Kubernetes cluster using `kubectl`. Given that my Postgres server connection details are:

```
host: mypostgres
port: 5432
username: postgres
password: 12345
```

And given that I *think* the command will be *something* like:

```
kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=postgres --restart=Never -- sh
```

What do I need to do so that I can deploy this image to my cluster, connect to my Postgres server and start running SQL command against it (for troubleshooting purposes)?

Comment: I mean, how important is it for the image to be lightweight? If it's really important, you can use `alpine` image instead of `busybox`. Otherwise, postgres has an official image which you can use for the client.

Comment: The Busybox image isn't based on Alpine. It's based on scratch. It only contains the busybox executable.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I made some changes (please see the edits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your primarily interested in troubleshooting, then you're probably looking for the `kubectl port-forward` command, which will expose a container port on your local host.  First, you'll need to deploy the Postgres pod; you haven't shown what your pod manifest looks like, so I'm going to assume a `Deployment` like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: postgres
  name: postgres
  namespace: sandbox
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: secret
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: example
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: example
        image: docker.io/postgres:13
        name: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: postgres
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
          name: postgres-data
      strategy: Recreate
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: postgres-data
```

Once this is running, you can access postgres with the `port-forward`
command like this:

```
kubectl -n sandbox port-forward deploy/postgres 5432:5432
```

This should result in:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5432 -> 5432
Forwarding from [::1]:5432 -> 5432
```

And now we can connect to Postgres using `psql` and run queries
against it:

```
$ psql -h localhost -U example example
psql (13.4)
Type "help" for help.

example=#
```

---

`kubectl port-forward` is only useful as a troubleshooting mechanism. If
you were trying to access your `postgres` pod from another pod, you
would create a `Service` and then use the service name as the hostname
for your client connections.

---

**Update**

If your goal is to deploy a *client* container so that you can log
into it and run `psql`, the easiest solution is just to `kubectl rsh`
into the postgres container itself. Assuming you were using the
`Deployment` shown earlier in this question, you could run:

```
kubectl rsh deploy/postgres
```

This would get you a shell prompt *inside* the postgres container. You
can run `psql` and not have to worry about authentication:

```
$ kubectl rsh deploy/postgres
$ psql -U example example
psql (13.4 (Debian 13.4-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

example=#
```

If you want to start up a separate container, you can use the `kubectl debug` command:

```
kubectl debug deploy/postgres
```

This gets you a root prompt in a debug pod. If you know the ip address
of the postgres pod, you can connect to  it using `psql`. To get
the address of the pod, run this on your local host:

```
$ kubectl get pod/postgres-6df4c549f-p2892 -o jsonpath='{.status.podIP}'
10.130.0.11
```

And then inside the debug container:

```
root@postgres-debug:/# psql -h 10.130.0.11 -U example example
```

In this case you would have to provide an appropriate password,
because you are accessing postgres from "another machine", rather than
running directly inside the postgres pod.

Note that in the above answer I've used the shortcut
`deploy/<deployment_name`, which avoids having to know the name of the
pod created by the `Deployment`. You can replace that with
`pod/<podname>` in all cases.

Comment: Thanks so much @larsks (+1) but just so I'm 100% clear, does this setup stand up a Postgres **server**? If so, thats _not_ what I'm looking for. I have an existing Postgres server running on my cluster, available at `mypostgres` (inside the cluster), and I now need to deploy a container to that service that has the Postgres client on it (so that I can SSH into it, connect to the server and issue some queries). Thanks for any clarification here!

Comment: I see; that was totally not clear from your question. I thought you were just looking for a way to troubleshoot a postgres server in Kubernetes, and this provides a viable solution. The interesting part isn't the "installing a server", which as I pointed out you have already done, but the use of port-forwarding to expose the postgres port locally so that you can interact with it. I'll try to update the answer in a bit in light of your comment.

Comment: See my updates; let me know if that helps.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again so much here!